# Selecting data from all the series of a mesurement influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I pushed some values into a measurement with no tags. Then I started pushing more values, but a with a tag this time.

Now if I execute 
`select * from measurement` I can see all the rows but the data pushed with no tags has value missing. I understand that this will create an another series
But how to see correct data for the previous series?
Is this not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *"the previous series"* you mean the data with no tags, than just pass a empty string into `WHERE` clause as a filter.

```
insert some_measurement value=1
insert some_measurement value=2
insert some_measurement,some_tag=tag value=3
insert some_measurement,some_tag=tag value=4
```

---

```
select * from some_measurement 

name: some_measurement
time                         some_tag value
----                         -------- -----
2018-02-28T11:20:01.3065712Z          1
2018-02-28T11:20:03.2416274Z          2
2018-02-28T11:20:24.5619333Z tag      3
2018-02-28T11:20:26.9859001Z tag      4
```

---

```
select value from some_measurement where some_tag=''

name: some_measurement
time                         value
----                         -----
2018-02-28T11:20:01.3065712Z 1
2018-02-28T11:20:03.2416274Z 2
```

Comment: There was some issue with my measurement, that's why it was not working for me. Accepting as an answer, as your solution works. Thanks!